# Unable to remove midi config

Tags: audio, midi

I am trying to get rid of a audio driver from my Mac (Mac OS Monterey 12.3.1) and on Audio MIDI Setup I can't remove it. The audio is named epocCam. can someone pls help me in removing it?

Comment: Have you checked the Elgato website's Support pages? There is an uninstall FAQ available.

Comment: I can't seem to find it or im looking at the wrong thing